# Populating checkboxlists from database

Tags: php

Is it possible to populate a checkboxlist from the database values? If so, please suggest how to do this.

```
$query2 = "select * from Products where CategoryID = '$CategoryName' ";
 mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
 $array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)){
$array[] = $row;}

foreach($array as $val)
 {
 if($val =='the checkbox value')
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But, [what have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Justing: Actually i have not tried anything as i am not getting the logic itself. Please let me know if any tutorial or examples are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" /> I have a bike<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" /> I have a car
</form>
```

These are the few steps you have to do.
1.Fetch the values from database.
2. Covert the values in array as they are stored as string by (,) separated.
3. Then

```
foreach($values as $val)
     {
          if($val =='Bike')
             {
                   $bikeflag = '1';
             }
            if($val =='Car')
             {
                   $carflag = '1';
             }

    }
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"  <?php if(isset($bikeflag ) =='1'){ ?>checked = checked <?php } ?>/> I have a bike<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"   <?php if(isset($carflag) =='1'){ ?>checked = checked <?php } ?>/> I have a car
</form>
```

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. But i did not get what 'the checkbox value' here. Please have a look above i have edited my code. i did not get what should be done further.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay i have edited my answer.Hopefully now you can understand it easily..

Answer (score 1):

1. Get values from database with the appropriate SQL query
2. Loop through results echoing out a checkbox element

Caveats

- Make sure each one has a unique name unless you want them to be an array. Then use array syntax for their name (e.g. name[])
- Make sure to give each one a unique value

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, its very much possible:

Fetch the records to be populated with the structure:

```
Id and value
```

Provide datasource of the checkedbox list as the fetched structured list as mentioned above.

```
Now define the value field of the checkboxlist as "Id" and text as "value"
```